# Backbone model success and error options

Tags: backbone.js

Adding success and error callback in backbone model#save doesn't work.

I upgraded to 0.9.10 which is the newest one and to my surprise

```
model.save{ 
  success : function(model, response, options){

  },

  error : function(model, response, options){

  });
```

doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: does the network request takes place when you call save? I think they changed their validation strategy in the latest backbone which prevents save method to work if the model is invalid

Answer (score 1):

The `options` object should be passed as the second argument. The first arguments is reserved for attributes you want to set in the save operation:

```
model.save({attr:'val'}, {
  success: function() { },
  error: function() { }
});
```

If you don't want to pass any new values to save, you can pass either and empty object (`{}`) or `null`.